# Access Front end multi-user issue

Tags: ms-access

I've split an access database, with the Back end on the shared drive and 2 front end instances on 2 seperate local machines. It works fine when both the users are logged in at the same time until If a user1 searches for an item X, user2's screen is popuated with the same search Item X, if user 2 searches for item Y, user1's search screen has item Y although the updates to any items is reflected to both users. I don't want both user's to have this concurrency search issues. If anyone could help me out with this. Thank you

Comment: Please show us the method you're using to do the searching.

Comment: It's basically a form which searches for an item and a subform which displays a list of options to select from. The user can then click on any option to view more information about that item.

Comment: The users are working in separate front-end databases.  But one user's search criteria somehow affects the information displayed to the other user.  That could happen if a search term is stored in a back-end table, and then a query references that table to filter the displayed "search results".

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what is being done. How can i resolve this shared screen kind of issue? Since, i need the updated information of the item to be displayed to all users, only if they search for it, and not just pop up on hteir screen

Comment: Never encountered this. Exactly how is the search criteria selected? UNBOUND combobox? Why are you storing a search term in a table?

Comment: Store the search term in a local table in the front-end and query it there.  Or modify the back-end table to include a `user_name` field in addition to the search term ... then adjust the query to reference the user's name when locating the search term.